# TestNG @Factory analog in JUnit 5

Tags: java, testng, junit5

In TestNG we can annotate test class constructor @Factory annotation and specify data provider for this factory like this:

```
@Factory(dataProvider = "dataProviderName")
```

And TestNG create instance of test class for each object returned by data provider.
In JUnit 5 I didn't found feature exactly like that. My question is, how I can reproduce that behavior in JUnit 5?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score -1):

Please, read a guide about Dynamic tests - https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests-examples

Also, dynamic tests can be parameterized (like data providers) with Sources - https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests-uri-test-source read this part of guide

Comment: Yes, but it is for just one test, not for tests class. I have separate tests in my test class, which use one source of parameters